# The error message "There are no input files to process" from jsdoc

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Jsdoc is installed locally ( npm install jsdoc ). I get the following error while trying to execute 
    
    `.\node_modules.bin\jsdoc --debug ./lib/JavaScriptSource.js`
    
Output:
    
    `DEBUG: JSDoc 3.3.0-dev (Sun, 15 Jun 2014 18:39:52 GMT)
    DEBUG: Environment info: {"env":{"conf":{"tags":{"allowUnknownTags":true},"templ
    ates":{"monospaceLinks":false,"cleverLinks":false,"default":{"outputSourceFiles"
    :true}},"source":{"includePattern":".+\.js(doc)?$","excludePattern":"(^|\/|\\
    )_"},"plugins":[]},"opts":{"_":["./lib/JavaScriptSource.js"],"debug":true,"destina
    tion":"./out/","encoding":"utf8"}}}
    There are no input files to process.`

```
JSDoc 3.3.0-dev (Sun, 15 Jun 2014 18:39:52 GMT)

Options:
-t, --template <value>       The path to the template to use. Default:
                             path/to/jsdoc/templates/default
-c, --configure <value>      The path to the configuration file.
                             Default: path/to/jsdoc/conf.json 
.....
</code>
```

Comment: Does `./lib/JavaScriptSource.js` exist?

Comment: Yes, it does exists. In jsdoc source jsdoc/cli.js, after the call to  method cli.scanFiles(), env.sourceFiles comes up empty. Haven't seen the code in detail around this place.

Comment: At line 263 for jsdoc/cli.js, I was able to execute a `code` var fileData = fs.readFileSync(env.opts._[0], 'utf8');
 console.log(fileData.toString()); `code` which displays the content. The env object is show in the original post.

Comment: Turns is an open bug in jsdoc where it does not process filepath's starting with "_". https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/308. Provides the solution as well.

Answer (score 16):

Turns is an open bug in jsdoc where it does not process filepath's starting with "_". github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/308. Provides the solution as well.

Where the default excludePattern (^|/|\)_ ignores paths starting with an underscore.

The solution quoted from https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/308

> "To change the default behavior:
>
> Copy conf.json.EXAMPLE to a new file, conf.json. You can put it in the
>   JSDoc directory or another directory. If you put it in another
>   directory, you will need to use the -c option to tell JSDoc where to
>   find it: jsdoc -c path/to/conf.json Open conf.json in a text editor.
>   Find the source.excludePattern property, and change it to an empty
>   string."

Comment: This is the intended behavior, not a bug, which is why that issue has been closed for a year and a half.

Comment: ok. "By default, JSDoc ignores files and **directories** that start with an underscore." so if my file path contains folder with bad name it will get ignored too.