# JSDoc not working in .MJS file with Rollup

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have the following...

```
/**
 * Represents a base element
 * @extends HTMLElement
 * @constructor
 */
export class Base extends HTMLElement {
...
}
```

When I run...

```
jsdoc src/jrg-base-element.mjs
```

Then I get...

> There are no input files to process.

I tried `--debug` and got...

> {"env":{"conf":{"plugins":[],"recurseDepth":10,"source":{"includePattern":".+\.js(doc|x)?$","excludePattern":"(^|\/|\\)*"},"sourceType":"module","tags":{"allowUnknownTags":true,"dictionaries":["jsdoc","closure"]},"templates":{"monospaceLinks":false,"cleverLinks":false,"default":{"outputSourceFiles":true}}},"opts":{"*":["src/jrg-base-element.mjs"],"debug":true,"destination":"./out/","encoding":"utf8"}}}

Which seems to be close to ([The error message "There are no input files to process" from jsdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412723/the-error-message-there-are-no-input-files-to-process-from-jsdoc)) but I don't know what to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it myself:

1. Install JSDoc:

   ```
    npm install -g jsdoc => OK
   ```
2. Create a dummy file, src/x.js:

   ```
    /**
     * Represents a base element
     * @extends HTMLElement
     * @constructor
     */
    function hello () {
      console.log ('Hello world!');
    }
   ```
3. Run `jsdoc src`
4. Check the results (default directory `"out/"`):

   [image]

In other words:

a) You may specify a JS file, but you'll typically specify a JS package directory.

b) By default, JSDoc doesn't recognize ".mjs"

Suggestion:

Specify a configuration file, and edit `source.includePatter=n`:

> https://jsdoc.app/about-configuring-jsdoc.html#specifying-input-files
>
> **Specifying input files**
>
> The source set of options, in combination with paths given to JSDoc on
> the command line, determines the set of input files that JSDoc uses to
> generate documentation.
>
> ```
> {
>     "source": {
>         "include": [ /* array of paths to files to generate documentation for */ ],
>         "exclude": [ /* array of paths to exclude */ ],
>         "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
>         "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> - **source.include**: An optional array of paths that contain files for which JSDoc should generate documentation. The paths given to JSDoc on
>   the command line are combined with these paths. You can use the -r
>   command-line option to recurse into subdirectories.
> - **source.exclude**: An optional array of paths that JSDoc should ignore. In JSDoc 3.3.0 and later, this array may include subdirectories of the
>   paths in source.include.
> - **source.includePattern**: An optional string, interpreted as a regular expression. If present, all filenames must match this regular
>   expression to be processed by JSDoc. By default, this option is set to
>   ".+.js(doc|x)?$", meaning that only files with the extensions .js,
>   .jsdoc, and .jsx will be processed.
> - **source.excludePattern**: An optional string, interpreted as a regular expression.  If present, any file matching this regular expression
>   will be ignored. By default, this option is set so that files
>   beginning with an underscore (or anything under a directory beginning
>   with an underscore) is ignored.

Comment: This pattern seems to have worked...

"source": {
        "includePattern": ".+\\.(m|c)?js(doc|x)?$"
 } 

To me this is a bug considering .CJS and .MJS are now standard and suggested conventions. I will open an issue in JSDoc.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and/or "accepting"  the response if you found it helpful.  PS: A good link on the subject of .mjs files: [Files with .mjs extension for JavaScript modules](https://medium.com/passpill-project/files-with-mjs-extension-for-javascript-modules-ced195d7c84a)